# Существует ли touch или его аналог под Windows?

Tags: unix, windows-7

При попытке вызвать команду touch в батнике или cmd, получаем:

```
"touch" не является внутренней или внешней командой, 
исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Существует ли аналог?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На выбор:

1. Cygwin: https://www.cygwin.com/
2. Msys: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys
3. Unxutils: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/
4. Если только время: https://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch, хотя тут рецептов море: делаем **touch.cmd** с таким содержимым:

   @COPY /B %1+,, %1
5. Написать свою утилиту :)

PS google рулит

PPS знали бы как sleep в винде делается, ммм....

Comment: *знали бы как sleep в винде делается*. ms/windows не удовлетворяет стандарту posix, потому всё, к posix-у относящееся, реализовать в этой операционной системе довольно сложно. впрочем, справедливо и обратное: знали бы вы, как в posix-совместимых операционных системах приходится делать вызовы ms/windows api… ммм…

Comment: Дополню: а если требуется создать пустой файл - то `copy nul file.txt` создаст его

Comment: спасибо, нагуглил прям-таки аналог `echo $null >> filename`, да у меня задачи на данный момент в общем-то простые, через консоль файлы-папки создавать, плагины для gulp, ну и другое так, по мелочи...

Comment: Вот еще одно отличное решение: Устанавливаем git под windows, в conemu настраиваем связку с git bash и все. Радость, счастье.

Comment: git под Windows внутрях ещё и msys ставит